# Storing FnMut in struct gives lifetime problems

Tags: rust

I'm trying to store a `FnMut` in a struct:

```
struct OpenVPNSocket {
    socket_send_callback: Option<Box<dyn FnMut(Vec<u8>) -> Result<(), ()>>>,
}

impl OpenVPNSocket {
    fn set_socket_send<F: FnMut(Vec<u8>) -> Result<(), ()>>(&mut self, callback: Box<F>) {
        self.socket_send_callback = Some(callback);
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `F` may not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:8:42
  |
7 |     fn set_socket_send<F: FnMut(Vec<u8>) -> Result<(), ()>>(&mut self, callback: Box<F>) {
  |                        -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `F: 'static +`
8 |         self.socket_send_callback = Some(callback);
  |                                          ^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `F` will meet its required lifetime bounds
```

I understand lifetime as something to do with references. However I don't use references. I don't see why my struct cannot store a `Box`. A `Box` lives as long as it's used.

**UPDATE:**

I have this example:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

pub type OnConsume = Arc<dyn Fn() -> Option<u8> + Send + Sync>;

struct Test {
    callback: OnConsume
}

impl Test {
    fn set_on_consume(&mut self, f: OnConsume) {
        self.callback = f;
    }
}
```

which works. What is the difference from the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

In Rust, values also have lifetimes. Take, for example, this struct:

```rust
struct RefWrapper<'a> {
    some_ref: &'a u32
}
```

An instance of `RefWrapper` is not a reference, but contains a lifetime. Since you're moving the box into the struct, which *could* live for the duration of the program (the method makes no guarantees as to when the struct instance could be dropped), the function *must* live for the maximum lifetime, the static lifetime.

Comment: If the closure lives for a shorter lifetime, it can similarly be specified with a lifetime parameter e.g. `Box<dyn 'a + FnMut...>`.

Comment: Then it wouldn't be able to be moved into the struct unless the struct then also obtained a lifetime.

Comment: Absolutely.  That’s what I meant.

Comment: @Aplet123 can you look at my update? Another similar callback works without problems when stored. Why for this one I have lifetime problems?

Answer (score 0):

All trait objects have lifetimes, the default implicit lifetime for boxed trait objects is `'static` so your struct's `socket_send_callback` actually has an implicit `+ 'static` bound. Shown in context:

```rust
struct OpenVPNSocket {
    socket_send_callback: Option<Box<dyn FnMut(Vec<u8>) -> Result<(), ()> + 'static>>,
}
```

Since the boxed trait object has to be bounded by a `'static` lifetime when you write a function to set this field the value itself must have a `'static` lifetime which is why the compiler suggests adding that explicit bound. Fixed example with added bound:

```rust
impl OpenVPNSocket {
    // notice the added 'static bound for F
    fn set_socket_send<F: FnMut(Vec<u8>) -> Result<(), ()> + 'static>(&mut self, callback: Box<F>) {
        self.socket_send_callback = Some(callback);
    }
}
```

With this change your code will compile. If you want to accept trait objects that aren't bounded by `'static` lifetimes then you can do that by making your `OpenVPNSocket` generic over lifetimes. This alternative solution also compiles:

```rust
struct OpenVPNSocket<'a> {
    socket_send_callback: Option<Box<dyn FnMut(Vec<u8>) -> Result<(), ()> + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> OpenVPNSocket<'a> {
    fn set_socket_send<F: FnMut(Vec<u8>) -> Result<(), ()> + 'a>(&mut self, callback: Box<F>) {
        self.socket_send_callback = Some(callback);
    }
}
```

The reason why this code works is because you define the type once and use it in multiple places, and in all places it has the implicit `'static` bound. Desugared:

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

pub type OnConsume = Arc<dyn Fn() -> Option<u8> + Send + Sync + 'static>;

struct Test {
    callback: OnConsume
}

impl Test {
    fn set_on_consume(&mut self, f: OnConsume) {
        self.callback = f;
    }
}
```

However you can do the exact same thing in your prior code as well:

```rust
type Callback = Box<dyn FnMut(Vec<u8>) -> Result<(), ()>>;

struct OpenVPNSocket {
    socket_send_callback: Option<Callback>,
}

impl OpenVPNSocket {
    fn set_socket_send(&mut self, callback: Callback) {
        self.socket_send_callback = Some(callback);
    }
}
```

The above also compiles, and the implicit `'static` bound is still there.